# Linq: Sorting by irregular order

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of Cities. Each City has a CarbonId (int)

I wish to sort a list of cities by this order CarbonId  :  3,6,2,7,9

Is there a way to sort by an array of CarbonId [3,6,2,7,9] ?

```
List<City> cities = db.GetCities.SortByIrreguylarCarbonId([3,6,2,7,9]??????)
```

Comment: How is the irregular order decided?

Comment: @test: It think order is already there? 3,6,2 etc...

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I can't tell if he has a different order and he wants the sort order output to be 3,6,2,7,9

Comment: 20k rating, and u can't solve this one on your own? ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the required method:

```
class City
{
    public int CarbonId { get; set; }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<City> OrderByIrregularCarbonId(
         IEnumerable<City> sequence,
         params int[] carbons)
    {
        return sequence.OrderBy(T => Array.IndexOf(carbons, T.CarbonId));
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] carbonOrder = new[] { 3, 6, 2, 7, 9 };

    List<City> cities = City.OrderByIrregularCarbonId(db.GetCities, carbonOrder).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create your comparison logic

```
private static int CompareCityByMyLogic(City x, City y)
{
  //put your logic here 
  return 0;
}
```

then use it

`db.GetCities.Sort(CompareCityByMyLogic)`;

Comment: I believe the question asks about what should go in `//put your logic here`

Comment: Also, there will be difficulties with `Sort` method as it may be not present in the database collection.